# launching program through sh script in Supervisord

Tags: python, sh, supervisord

I have a script run.sh which launches a python pub-sub listener as follows:

```
export MY_ENV_VAR='/root/config/'
python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/listener/main.py
```

And I setup Supervisord so that it allows me to run my script as follows:

```
[program:Listener]
command=/bin/bash run.sh
directory=/root/listener
process_name=%(program_name)s
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
```

My question is: when I go to my Supervisord UI at port 9001, and press `STOP` next to the Listener line, do I really stop my Listener? I have the impression that since supervisord is pointing to the `.sh` script, it does not stop the python script when I click on `STOP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to specify

> stopasgroup=true

parameter in your configuration file.

So supervisord will send kill signal to child processes too:

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html